# How can I read the string value from the _storageToken.read() call?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

I have this construction in my homepage widget which is suppose to get the saved token. Now this returns a Future. So How can I read the token string? I tried storedToken.toString() but it returns Future<String?> not what I expected. I am expecting a String value like "fhsdjkfhs.djkfhsdjkfhsdjk"

```
void initState(){
    const _storageToken = FlutterSecureStorage();
    storedToken = _storageToken.read(key: 'jwt');
    print(storedToken);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_storageToken.read() returns a Future, so you have to await it in order to get the value.

The problem is, you can't perform async/await action directly on the initState.
If you still want to call that _storageToken.read() on the initState, you can use this workaround.

```
void initState(){
   /// Initialize Flutter Secure Storage
   const _storageToken = FlutterSecureStorage();
   
   /// Await your Future here (This function only called once after the layout is Complete) 
   WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
       final storedToken = await _storageToken.read(key: 'jwt');
       print(storedToken);
   });
}
```

Comment: So what is the proper way then without using a work around?

Comment: @dianesis Use some kind of state management to handle that data read (ex: flutter_bloc). Or, you can use Future Builder inside your "build" method.

Comment: Can I do this at void main() ? runApp?

Comment: @dianesis Sure, you can do it. Add "async" to your main function, and WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized().

Example: Future<void> main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); 
await _storageToken.read(key: 'jwt');
runApp(MyApp());
}

Comment: And is this appropiate? Is it normal to check if the jwt token is stored before doing anything esle? if is not then show a login or register screen.

Comment: @dianesis It depends on your use cases, technically, it's fine to check your token on the main() function. But, it would be better if you create a custom Splash Screen, and check your token there.

Comment: But the thing is that every time I start my app it says that splash screen was provided but is deprecated in flutter.

Comment: @dianesis I assume you're debugging on Android, if so, then it actually has nothing to do with your dart code. Just modify the Manifest to get rid of that message. You can follow this instruction if you want to : https://madushalakruwan.medium.com/a-splash-screen-was-provided-to-flutter-but-this-is-deprecated-flutter-2-5-eea78cb1731b